# Test for following sibling not having argument

Tags: xslt

Consider the following xml file:

```
<main>
  <sub>
    <div n="1"/>
    <div n="2"/>
    <div n="3"/>
    <div n="-">
  </sub>
  <sub>
    <div n="1"/>
    <div n="2"/>
    <div/>
  </sub>
  <sub>
    <div n="1"/>
    <div n="2"/>
    <div n="-"/>
  </sub>
</main>
```

I want to output only the value of the last `@n` that is a digit and is followed either by a `div` with no `@n` or one with `@n = '-'`. The following test in a template that matches `div`s outputs all `@n`s containing digits...

```
<xsl:if test="
      matches(@n, '[0-9]') and
      following-sibling::div[not(@n) or @n='-']
  ">
```

I also tried:

```
<xsl:if test="
      matches(@n, '[0-9]') and
      (not(following-sibling::div[@n]) or
       following-sibling::div[@n='-'])
  ">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your example, every `div` except the last one in each `sub` has a following sibling that meets your criteria. I suspect you want to test only the immediately following sibling. Though I am not entirely sure  - your formulation of the rule as well as the example are somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you, adding [1] after `div` seems to do the trick. So I *did* miss something.